# Aligning elements within a div - strange behaviour

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying to align a div and an image within a div element, such that they are centred horizontally. This seems to work correctly up until I specify the img element's src attribute - assigning it an image; at which point it appears like so:

[image: picture of the problem]

The source code is as follows (HTML):

```
<div id="sContainer">
    <input id="sBox" type="text" />
    <img id="sButton" alt="Search" src="images/searchglass.jpg" />
</div>
```

and (CSS):

```css
#sContainer
{
background-color:yellow;
float:left;
text-align:center;
width:560px;
}
```

For those interested in what it looks like when the image has not got a value in the src attribute, and so displays the alt text, this is what it looks like:

[image: picture of problem]

Anyone know how to solve this irritating problem?

**Edit:**

More HTML code:

```
<div class="center" id="header">

    <div id="leftContainer"></div>

    <div id="sContainer">
        <input id="sBox" type="text" />
        <img id="sButton" alt="Search" src="images/searchglass.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div id="rightContainer"></div>

</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.center
{
clear:both;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:960px;
}

#header
{
background-color:gray;
height:50px;
}

#rightContainer
{
background-color:red;
float:left;
width:200px;
}

#leftContainer
{
background-color:green;
float:left;
width:200px;
}

#sBox
{
border-bottom-color:black;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-width:1px;
border-left-color:black;
border-left-style:solid;
border-left-width:1px;
border-top-color:black;
border-top-style:solid;
border-top-width:1px;
height:18px;
padding:5px;
width:348px;
}

#sContainer
{
background-color:yellow;
float:left;
text-align:center;
width:560px;
}

#searchContainer > *
{
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you float the image left, as well?

Comment: They are correctly placed together but they are no longer centred horizontally in the parent div (container).

Answer (score 1):

When the image has a valid `src` attribute, it gains dimensions, and therefore forces the height on its parent element. If you want to keep the text box and image as inline elements, you could adjust the line-height of the parent to the image height:

```
#sContainer
{
    background-color:yellow;
    float:left; // btw, does this need to be floated?
    text-align:center;
    width:560px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

However, this won't render consistently in all browsers, because by default those elements are vertically aligned to the baseline. You want to vertically align all child elements of `#sContainer` to the top or middle.

```
#sContainer > *
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This worked, but they are now not joined horizontally, only vertically. The same result as the newer comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your `img` the `vertical-align` css style, for example:

```
#sContainer img
{
    vertical-align: -4px;
}
```

Comment: This worked, but they are now not joined horizontally, only vertically.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/QUk5m/

My suggestions:

1. Put the searchbar and the search button in a `div`, called `inside-container` in this example
2. Float the searchbar to the left, and the search button to the right
3. Give the outside container, or `#sContainer`, a height, since you have floated elements inside it
4. Give each element a height and width!

Obviously, make the changes to my jsFiddle that better suit your heights/widths, and naming structure.

Comment: It's already in a container, but I tried what you said and I get the same result (it looks like the first image).

Comment: The code I posted is certainly working, you probably have CSS that's interfering with this.

Comment: Edited the original post to show more HTML. Honestly, I've been scratching my head about this all day - I'm going to bald.